# Traversing table columns by class name

Tags: jquery, traversal

```
<tr>
  <td class = "edit edit_c1">C1</td>
  <td>C2</td>
  <td class = "edit edit_c3">C3</td>
  <td>C4</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td class = "edit edit_c1">C1</td>
  <td>C2</td>
  <td class = "edit edit_c3">C3</td>
  <td>C4</td>
<tr>
```

I have some Jeditable code that runs on ".edit_c1, edit_c2 etc". I want to traverse to the next editable column on TAB. I have another class "edit" to identify editable columns. I am assuming nextall() should work but none of the options below gets me the handle to the next editable column (TD with class = "edit").

```
$(".edit").keypress(function (event) {
                var td = $(this).closest('td');
                console.log(this);
                // returns <td class="edit edit-c1" style="white-space:nowrap">
                switch (event.keyCode) {
                    // TAB   
                    case 9:
                        console.log("TABBED");
                        console.log($(this).closest('td').next('td[@class=edit]'));
                        //Above logs [td] a handle to C2 instead of C3
                        console.log($(this).closest('td').nextAll(':has(.edit):first').find('.edit'));
                        //Above logs []
                        console.log($(this).nextAll(':has(.edit):first').find('.edit'));
                        //Above logs []
                        console.log($(this).closest('td').next().find('.edit'));
                        //Above logs []
                        break;
                }
            });
```

The code does work to a point where I see the console.log messages in firebug. Jeditable portion of the code below.

```
            $('.edit-c1').editable(function (value, settings) {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
                id = tr[0].id;
                //comment the line below if you want to test
                //saveWSField(id, value, "C1");
                return (value);
            }, {
                type: 'text',
                onblur: 'submit'
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked in too much detail at what jeditable injects into the DOM to make things editable, but it seems to inject a small form.

With this in mind, the following works for me:

html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class = "edit edit_c1"><form><input type="text" value="C1" /></form></td>
            <td>C2</td>
            <td class = "edit edit_c2"><form><input type="text" value="C3" /></form></td>
            <td>C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "edit edit_c1"><form><input type="text" value="r2C1" /></form></td>
            <td>C2</td>
            <td class = "edit edit_c2"><form><input type="text" value="r2C3" /></form></td>
            <td>C4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the following javascript:

```
$(".edit").keypress(function(event) {
    var td = $(this).closest('td');
    console.log(this);
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        // TAB   
    case 9:
        console.log("TABBED");
        console.log($(this).html());
        var $ntd = $(this).nextAll('.edit');
        if ($ntd.length === 0) {
            console.log($(this).parent().nextAll('tr').html());
            $ntd = $(this).parent().nextAll('tr').children('td.edit').first();
        }
        // $ntd should hold what we need
        console.log($ntd.html());
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: OK I got it!

`$(this).nextAll("td.edit").first()` WORKS!

When I used `$(this).next("td.edit")` (doesn't work) my current focused element is TD of "C1", "Next" goes to TD of "C2" and since it doesn't have "class=edit" it returns nothing.

When I used `$(this).nextAll("td.edit").first()` (works) my current focused element is TD and it returns ALL siblings with "class=edit" and I choose the first one to move to the next editable column from the current column. Now I have to figure out how to go to the nezt row... lol. How fun!

Comment: What do you mean by "go to the next row"?  The if statement (if ($ntd.length === 0)) may do this already, if I understand what you're trying to do - i.e. when on the last input of the row, it returns the first one of the next row.

Comment: Mutex, I edited your answer now realized I should have left it as it is. Not sure how to rollback. Is it possible for you to edit your answer again?

Comment: I don't think you edited my answer - still looks correct to me.

EDIT: Oh actually I see the edit now - OK, I rejected it :)

Comment: Sweet! It looks good now and I understand what you are doing :)! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This is not trivial as the structure of `<table>` makes it difficult to determine the next `<td>` because it may not be the child of the same `<tr>`. Meaning if something is not found you would need to traverse up to the parent `<tr>` then to the next `<tr>` sibling, then the next `<td>` child.

Try something like:

```
// ASSUMPTION: td is the current focused element
next_td = td.next('td.edit');

if (next_td.length < 1) {
  next_td = td.closest('tr').children('td.edit').first();
}

if (next_td.length < 1) {
  // nothing left to tab
}
else {
  // focus next_td...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! In my code above console.log(this) returns <td class="edit edit-c1" style="white-space:nowrap"> which means the current context is indeed on the first td. So I tried console.log($(this).next('td.edit'); and it didn't return anything :(. So generally it's the correct syntax right? May be i'm reading firebug wrong? Firebug log shows [] for next('td.edit'). For next() it returns [td] which is C2 and not C3.

Comment: The code I provided works for your spec. I tested it. Try mine and be sure `td` is the current context. Let me know.

Comment: OK what I just noticed was "Next" just goes to the next element and returns the element only if the selector matches. It doesn't return the first matching element. So I think I have to use NextAll to traverse all the siblings and find the first one matching the class. I'll dig more. Your solution would work if I want to traverse back to the tr and come back to the children but I don't want to loose focus on the current td i'm on. Really appreciate your response!!!

Comment: Jason, really appreciate your effort! From your answer I stole "td.edit".

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't bind a keypress event to a td element... how are you gaining focus on the td to begin with?

Try this:

```
$(".edit").delegate('input','keydown',function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        // TAB   
        case 9:
          var nexted = $(this).parents('tr').find('td.edit:gt('+$(this).index()+'):first');
          nexted.trigger('click');
          return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, new to this, couldn't find a comment button.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the JEditable code portion of it makes it editable.. and I can successfully run this code when I press tab and see the Console.log messages in firebug. Hope that helps.  $('.edit-c1').editable(function (value, settings) {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
                    id = tr[0].id;
                    saveWSField(id, value, "C1");
                    return (value);
                }, {
                    type: 'text',
                    onblur: 'submit'
                });

Comment: check original answer, hope that helps